# How to select radio button when tapped on the container?

Tags: flutter

Basically, there is a row with two containers with the child as radio buttons. The containers change colour according to the selected radio button but I want the containers to change colours by tapping on them and not exactly by tapping the radio button.

**Code:**

```
Container(
            height: 60,
            width: 130,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _radioBtnVal == 'manual' ? AMBER : WHITE,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Radio<String>(
                    //activeColor: WHITE,
                    activeColor: Colors.red,
                    value: "manual",
                    groupValue: _radioBtnVal,
                    onChanged: _handleChange),
                Text(
                  "Manual",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: _radioBtnVal == 'manual' ? WHITE : BLACK,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ), 
 SizedBox(width: 80),
            Container(
              height: 60,
              width: 130,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: _radioBtnVal == 'video' ? AMBER : WHITE,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Radio<String>(
                      //activeColor: WHITE,
                      activeColor: Colors.red,
                      value: "video",
                      groupValue: _radioBtnVal,
                      onChanged: _handleChange),
                  Text(
                    "Video Call",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: _radioBtnVal == 'video' ? WHITE : BLACK,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Here is an image of what the output looks like.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the containers with gesture detectors and every time the container is tapped you have to pass a value to the function that handles the radio buttons and setstate. I have updated your code to get the desired output.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
      const MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: RadioTest()));
}

class RadioTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const RadioTest({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RadioTest> createState() => _RadioTestState();
}

class _RadioTestState extends State<RadioTest> {
  String _radioBtnVal = "";

  _handleChange(String? value) {
    setState(() {
      _radioBtnVal = value.toString();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
                _handleChange('manual');
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 60,
              width: 130,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: _radioBtnVal == 'manual' ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Radio<String>(
                      //activeColor: WHITE,
                      activeColor: Colors.red,
                      value: "manual",
                      groupValue: _radioBtnVal,
                      onChanged: _handleChange),
                  Text(
                    "Manual",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: _radioBtnVal == 'manual'
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 80),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
                _handleChange('video');
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 60,
              width: 130,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: _radioBtnVal == 'video' ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Radio<String>(
                      //activeColor: WHITE,
                      activeColor: Colors.red,
                      value: "video",
                      groupValue: _radioBtnVal,
                      onChanged: _handleChange),
                  Text(
                    "Video Call",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: _radioBtnVal == 'video'
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```